# Problems with DeserializeObject with an json array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, object, serialization

So I have a problem with DeserializeObject with an json array and I cant find what I am doing wrong here:

```
{"name":"Pannbiff n\u00f6tf\u00e4rs stekt","number":1128,"nutrientValues":
  {"energyKj":694,"energyKcal":166,"protein":17.2,"fat":7.6,"carbohydrates":7}}
```

My model looks like this:

And my code looks like:

`var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
var jsonSerializer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseText);`

```
public class Asware
{
    public IEnumerable<NutrientValues> nutrientValues { get; set; }

}

public class NutrientValues
{
    public int energyKcal { get; set; }
    public double protein { get; set; }
    public double carbohydrates { get; set; }
    public int fat { get; set; }
}
```

Can't see what can be wrong here I have also tried: 
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject>(responseText)

Comment: It seems like C#.Please, add the language tag.

Comment: what is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that in your source JSON, `nutrientValues` is a single object, not an array of objects.

If you change your model as follows it should serialise correctly:

`public class Asware
{
    public NutrientValues nutrientValues { get; set; }
}`

Alternatively, if you have control of the JSON, then you can modify it to contain an array of nutrients as follows, the `[ ]` characters indicate multiple items.

`{"name":"Pannbiff n\u00f6tf\u00e4rs stekt","number":1128,"nutrientValues":
  [{"energyKj":694,"energyKcal":166,"protein":17.2,"fat":7.6,"carbohydrates":7}]}`